# Random text is padded to CSS selectors when loading them using Webpack?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, import, webpack

For example `.rc-menu` turned to `.index__rc-menu__FStjN` and so on for all of the selectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out the config for [CSS Loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader). By default the name is something like this, but can be changed:

```
{
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
        modules: true,
        localIdentName: '[path][name]__[local]--[hash:base64:5]',
        getLocalIdent: (context, localIdentName, localName, options) => {
          return 'whatever_random_class_name'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! could you elaborate on the reason for this practice? I mean padding a hash, doesn't that make the CSS classes unusable?

Comment: Actually, it makes them more usable (or **reusable**). The idea has to do with [CSS Modules](https://github.com/css-modules/css-modules). In a React app, for example, I could have 2 unrelated Components that both have a class `.container`. If their individual CSS files have different definitions for what a `.container` is, then we'd have a conflict. This allows you to reuse classes across components without worrying about conflicts at all.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again.